# How to Fill jbutton

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

I want to fill a jbutton and all i find on the web is changing background and foreground colors, which is not what i am looking for.

```
public GameOfLife () {
    frame = new JFrame("2 player Game of Life");
    frame.setSize(505, 533);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    buttons = new JButton[10][10];

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
           buttons[i][j] = new JButton();

            buttons[i][j].setBounds(i*50+2, j*50+2, 50, 50);
            frame.add(buttons[i][j]);
            buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            //buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
            buttons[i][j].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            buttons[i][j].setOpaque(true);

        }
    }

    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

The setBackground only changes what is in the back of the button and setForeground only changes the color of the text in the button (if there is any). The button here is always white

Screenshot of the GUI. [image: Here]

So instead of changing the background color (here red and blue)i want to change the filling of the button (here white). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: (1-) *which is not what i am looking for.* - well, we can't guess what you are looking for. You actually have to ask a question if you want help. Also, don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout manager. You can easily use a `GridLayout`.

Comment: So what I want is to change the filling of the button which is white by default, instead of changing the background of the button. Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe you want to set the icon?

Comment: I have never seen a white background like that. What OS and version of Java are you use. Post a [mre] demonstrating the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test the code you post.

Comment: I have never seen a white background like that. What OS and version of Java are you using. What LAF are you using. Post a [mre] demonstrating the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test the code you post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compilable example that uses icons to change the face.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Icony{
    static JButton make(Color r){
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(r);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
        g.dispose();
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setOpaque(false);
        button.setBackground( Color.RED);
        button.setIcon( new ImageIcon(img) );
        return button;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("button");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        panel.add(make(Color.RED));
        panel.add(make(Color.BLUE));
        panel.add(make(Color.GREEN));
        panel.add(make(Color.YELLOW));
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```